# Connecting RING Video Doorbell to Friedland 454 chime unit

Tags: doorbell

I have a Friedland 454 unit, with a front and rear bell push, mains wired in (no batteries).

It is correctly wired as per [Haggis](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/80293/purpose-of-mercury-switch-in-old-doorbell) post with a front and back bellpush.

- The terminals are numbered, clockwise from top left: 3, 0, 2, 1, 4.
- Front-door bell-push connected to 0 and 1.
- Back-door bell-push connected to 0 and 2 (which I've disconnected and you can see taped up on top left).
- Mercury tilt switch connected across 1 and 2.
- Transformer jumper wire connects 2 and 4

If I wanted to connect a Ring Video Doorbell WIRED to the front bellpush (I don't care about rear bellpush) what do I need to do?  There is a jumper cable in the box but not sure which terminals to connect together to override everything and push power to the front bellpush wires (in order to power the Ring unit).

[image]

PS. I don't mind if the chime no longer works when doing this, I just need the power running to the door button.

Comment: Can you measure AC voltage from 0 to 3?

Comment: When measuring between 0-3 I get a fluctuating current / high is about .026-.030 and low of .015-.018ish

Comment: Why are you measuring current instead of voltage?

Comment: Sorry, I meant volts.  The meter on v-2 and registers a fluctuating .025ish-.032ish which seems stupidly low unless I'm doing something wrong.

Answer (score 1):

two options:

Connect 1 and 3: that will send power to the button location,  the chime will no longer work.

Connect 1 and 2: that will defeat the repeat mechanism, other than that the chime will continue to work the button location will see continuous current.  I don't know if that will be enough for the Ring.

Comment: Great that's really useful.  I assume if the current is not enough I need to find the transformer and upgrade it to something chunkier right?

Comment: yes that's right.

Comment: Apparently these run off a 6V transformer,  that's definately not enough for a Ring, (which needs 12-24V)